# Zipping Files using util.zip No directory

Tags: java, zip

I have the following situation:
I am able to zip my files with the following method:

```
public boolean generateZip(){
    byte[] application = new byte[100000];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // These are the files to include in the ZIP file
    String[] filenames = new String[]{"/subdirectory/index.html", "/subdirectory/webindex.html"};

    // Create a buffer for reading the files

    try {
        // Create the ZIP file

        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(baos);

        // Compress the files
        for (int i=0; i<filenames.length; i++) {
            byte[] filedata  = VirtualFile.fromRelativePath(filenames[i]).content();
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(filedata);

            // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filenames[i]));

            // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(application)) > 0) {
                out.write(application, 0, len);
            }

            // Complete the entry
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
        }

        // Complete the ZIP file
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error generating ZIP.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    downloadzip(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

This works perfectly and I can download the xy.zip which contains the following directory and file structure:
subdirectory/
----index.html
----webindex.html

My aim is to completely leave out the subdirectory and the zip should only contain the two files. Is there any way to achieve this?
(I am using Java on Google App Engine).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure the files contained in the `filenames` array are unique if you leave out the directory, change your line for constructing `ZipEntry`s:

```
String zipEntryName = new File(filenames[i]).getName();
out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(zipEntryName));
```

This uses [java.io.File#getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29)

Comment: Brilliant Solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Commons io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to list all your files, then read them to an `InputStream`

Replace the line below

```
String[] filenames = new String[]{"/subdirectory/index.html", "/subdirectory/webindex.html"}
```

with the following

```
    Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("/subdirectory"), new String[]{"html"}, true);
    for (File file : files)
    {
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] filedata = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileStream);
        //From here you can proceed with your zipping.
    }
```

Let me know if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `isDirectory()` method on `VirtualFile`